# detect the end of a file in AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, avaudioplayernode

I have set up an audio multitrack player using apple's AVFoundation. I use nine AVAudioPlayerNodes attached to an AVAudioEngine and they are played at precisely the same time. In spriteKit, in my game scene, I would like to detect the end of the file in any of the AVAudioPlayerNodes so that I can run subsequent code. How do I do that? Unfortunately AVAudioPlayerNodes don't have the same convenient functions as the simple AVAudioPlayer class. Here is the multiTrack function:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

var onesie = AVAudioPlayer()
var singleTrack = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackOne = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackTwo = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackThree = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackFour = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackFive = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackSix = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackSeven = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackEight = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var trackNine = AVAudioPlayerNode()

//variables to hold NSURLs as AVAudioFiles for use in AudioPlayer Nodes.
var single = AVAudioFile()
var one = AVAudioFile()
var two = AVAudioFile()
var three = AVAudioFile()
var four = AVAudioFile()
var five = AVAudioFile()
var six = AVAudioFile()
var seven = AVAudioFile()
var eight = AVAudioFile()
var nine = AVAudioFile()

//varibles for audio engine and player nodes. The "mixer" is part of     the engine and already hooked up to the output
var engine = AVAudioEngine()

//reference the mixer
let mainMixer = engine.mainMixerNode

func audioMultiTrack(trackOneFN: String, trackTwoFN: String, trackThreeFN: String, trackFourFN: String, trackFiveFN: String, trackSixFN: String, trackSevenFN: String, trackEightFN: String, trackNineFN: String){

/*access audio filess for audio players (tracks)*/

//1
guard let trackOneFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackOneFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}

//2
guard let trackTwoFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackTwoFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//3
guard let trackThreeFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackThreeFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//4
guard let trackFourFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackFourFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//5
guard let trackFiveFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackFiveFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//6
guard let trackSixFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackSixFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//7
guard let trackSevenFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackSevenFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//8
guard let trackEightFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackEightFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}
//9
guard let trackNineFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(trackNineFN, withExtension: "mp3") else {
    fatalError("File not found.")
}

//place NSURLs in AVAudioFile variables
//1
do {
    try one = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackOneFile)

} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track one file.")
}
//2
do {
    try two = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackTwoFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track two file.")
}
//3
do {
    try three = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackThreeFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track three file.")
}
//4
do {
    try four = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackFourFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track four file.")
}
//5
do {
    try five = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackFiveFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track five file.")
}
//6
do {
    try six = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackSixFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track six file.")
}
//7
do {
    try seven = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackSevenFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track six file.")
}
//8
do {
    try eight = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackEightFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track six file.")
}
//9
do {
    try nine = AVAudioFile(forReading: trackNineFile)
} catch {
    fatalError("error loading track six file.")
}


/*hook up audio units*/

//attach audio players (tracks) to audio engine
engine.attachNode(trackOne)
engine.attachNode(trackTwo)
engine.attachNode(trackThree)
engine.attachNode(trackFour)
engine.attachNode(trackFive)
engine.attachNode(trackSix)
engine.attachNode(trackSeven)
engine.attachNode(trackEight)
engine.attachNode(trackNine)

//connect the tracks to the mixer
engine.connect(trackOne, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackTwo, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackThree, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackFour, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackFive, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackSix, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackSeven, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackEight, to: mainMixer, format: nil)
engine.connect(trackNine, to: mainMixer, format: nil)

//connect audio files to audio players (tracks)
trackOne.scheduleFile(one, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackTwo.scheduleFile(two, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackThree.scheduleFile(three, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackFour.scheduleFile(four, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackFive.scheduleFile(five, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackSix.scheduleFile(six, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackSeven.scheduleFile(seven, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackEight.scheduleFile(eight, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
trackNine.scheduleFile(nine, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)

//try to start the audio engine
do {
    try engine.start()
} catch {
    print("error starting engine")
}
//function to create a precice time to start all audio players (tracks)
func startTime () ->AVAudioTime{
    let samplerate = one.processingFormat.sampleRate
    let sampleTime = AVAudioFramePosition(samplerate)
    let time = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: sampleTime, atRate: samplerate)
    return time
}

//start audio players (tracks) at precise time
trackOne.playAtTime(startTime())
trackTwo.playAtTime(startTime())
trackThree.playAtTime(startTime())
trackFour.playAtTime(startTime())
trackFive.playAtTime(startTime())
trackSix.playAtTime(startTime())
trackSeven.playAtTime(startTime())
trackEight.playAtTime(startTime())
trackNine.playAtTime(startTime())

}
```

Comment: Use the `completionHandler`s...

Comment: yes, but in order to use a completion handler I need to know that the task has been completed, and AVAudioPlayerNodes connected to an AVAudioEngine don't 'stop' when the file is completed, everything is manual

Comment: From the docs: *completionHandler*, Called after the buffer has completely played or the player is stopped. May be nil.

Comment: No that completion handler only indicates that the file has finished being "scheduled" to play (which happens almost instantly). It does not indicate that a file has finished playing.